# How do I make my search easy ?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server, rdlc

I have a table in SQL which stores

```
SchemeName, Description of item, Quantity, Unit, Rate, Amount
```

I am making a report in which I will just put SchemeName and on basis of that report will show up but problem is that SchemeName is quite long and typing that will require a lot of time and prone to errors. So any other idea ?

Note: Each scheme contains description, quantity, unit, rate, amount and upon searching SchemeName whole report will show i.e. where SchemeName= @SchemeName

Comment: Can you use wildcard search?  WHERE SchemeName LIKE 'First few chars%'?

Comment: What about using combobox with all the available schema names?

Comment: names are very long, won't look good in box. @Nissim

Comment: @KyleB. great. I had this idea too but thought that it might not be the great solution so SHOULD I GO FOR IT ?

Comment: how about using a descriptive names in the combobox and 'translate' them to the long schema name when the user requests the data?

Comment: Totally go for it :) .   Best way to find out is to try it, and continue refining if you find it doesn't work well after that.